# How to call custom function with arguments and return value inside the recipe?

Tags: makefile

My working directory looks as follows:

```
src/my_module/main.c
src/my_module/inc/my_header.h
obj/my_module
```

`main.c` includes `my_header.h`.

In my `makefile` the function `GET_INC` is supposed to return the include files based on the current module. Unfortunately, I am not able to process the return value properly, although there are similar problem descriptions in the Internet.

Please consider this very easy example:

```
OBJ=obj/my_module/main.o

# The original function is more complicated. In the end it echos a variable with all includes.
GET_INC = $$(X=src/$1/inc; \
    echo "$$X";)

prog: $(OBJ)
    @echo "$@ built."

# At first, we compute module name (here: my_module), which is then passed to GET_INC. 
obj/%.o: src/%.c
    @module=$$(echo $* | cut -d'/' -f1); \
    INC=$(call GET_INC,$$module); \
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $$INC;
```

Unfortunately, the variable INC remains empty, even though the function call works. I have the following questions:

1. How can I store the output of `GET_INC` in the variable `X` and then pass it to my compiler?
2. I am wondering if this solution is efficient, since I call the same function for every single .c file. As the `INC` depends on the current path, I cannot call it outside of the rule. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Your approach seems to work; whether there is a better way depends on details of the "more complicated" function. 2. If you mean that you'd like to reuse `INC` for each of the object files you build for that module, yes, that can be done, but we should settle 1 first.

Comment: The solution for the first question is far easier than expected. Concerning the second one, do you have suggestions about efficiency? INC does not change for a given module, but it is still recomputed for all source files for a given module. I'd need some way of precomputing INC.

Comment: You may want to improve INC for other reasons, I don't efficiency is a major issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work, apart from last line, which should be :

```
$(CC) $< -o $@ -I $$INC;
```

for debugging purposes, you can try :

```
echo $(CC) $< -o $@ -I $$INC;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was too easy ;).

Answer (score 0):

(You've left some important details out, so I'll have to make some educated guesses.)

If the function that builds the path to the `inc` directory works (and it seems that it does), then you can take the thing that it needs (part of the object path? call it `MODULE`), calculate the path at the module level and pass it down to the object rules.

```
MODULE := my_module
OBJS = obj/$(MODULE)/main.o obj/$(MODULE)/other.o

prog: INC=$(call GET_INC,$(MODULE))
prog: $(OBJS)

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@ -I$(INC)
```